# create a dataframe from a csv with only 1 column incl. data like this: [1,2,3], 0, 100

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe

I cannot use the comma separator, because there are also commas in the first elements in the list.

Maybe I have to split at first at "]" and create 2 columns and then replace the commas in the first column. But I think, that's not the recommended way.

[image: img]

what I have tried:

[image: img]

After uploading the data.csv, created in Excel, to the Jupiter Notebook, the columns seem to be gone, therefore I cannot use the A-Attribute proposed. Is there a similar way?

[csv without columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjjza.png)

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question, but in csv you can use double quotes `"` for columns that contains commas. `"[0,1,2]",0,10`

Comment: in your sample file there are three headers what you want to do with them merge it into single header  or ignore them

Comment: Avoid posting pictures of plain-text in your question.  It is unnecessary and prevents your code or input data from being copy & pasted into an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You might experiment by creating a valid `Dataframe` in Python then output it with [`pandas.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) to see how pandas expects CSV dataframes to be formatted (assuming it should be able to "round-trip" its own dataframes).

I tested (with my minimal Python, and zero pandas experience) the following at https://repl.it/languages/python3:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'list': [[5,6,7,8]],
                   'true': 0,
                   'amount': 210})
csv = df.to_csv(index=False)
print(csv)
```

and the output was:

```
list,true,amount
"[5, 6, 7, 8]",0,210
```

The leading spaces in the list field were added by `pandas.to_csv`, but I doubt they are required by the `pandas.read_csv` parser.

This result is what I would have assumed to be the case in any event, since that is the defined means of including commas in a field in CSV.  Quoted fields are optional, but required for fields containing commas.

So your CSV data should be:

```
list,true,amount
"[5,6,7,8]",0,210
"[2,2,0]",1,110
"[2,7]",0,200
```

If a field itself contains double-quotes, then the double-quote is repeated as in the example at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

```
1997,Ford,E350,"Super, ""luxurious"" truck"
```

Where the string `Super, "luxurious" truck` is a single string field containing both commas and double-quotes.

Comment: The data is poorly formatted in their CSV file. Using `literal_eval` you can convert multiple data types into a tuple. Check my answer for more detail.

Comment: @DeepankarSharma : I don't think it was necessary to advertise your answer by commenting in mine.  Yours explains how to cope with the broken CSV, mine explains how to _correct_ the CSV format to be directly parsable by `pandas.read_csv`.  Neither answer is incorrect, yours is suitable if there already exists a large amount of data formatted like that, and mine is more suited if it is possible at this point to correct the CSV format.

Comment: there's no need to be so hostile, especially towards someone who's new and trying to contribute more in this community. If sharing a different approach for solving a problem with you looks like an advertisement, then the problem lies in your own perception.

Comment: You should not see that as hostility - that was not my intent.  Your answer is clear enough for all to see _on the same page_, "sharing" it was unnecessary.  It might appear as if you are saying _"this answer is not correct, look at mine"_ put perhaps that is not what you intended and I don't think that is the case.  If it is not correct please just say that and what is wrong with it.  The fact that the CSV is invalid is indicated in this question in any case.  I am no expert in pandas or Python, I only came across it because it was mis-tagged "embedded" which is my expertise.

Comment: Thank you Clifford, but the data.csv is a given data set, just simplified. I need the output that Deepankar Sharma described, unfortunately the columns from Excel seem to be gone by uploading the data.csv to the jupiter notebook. Maybe you have any other idea?

Comment: @Losolak : As I said, I am no expert - you mistagged your question "embedded", which is the only reason I came across it.  I know about CSV and read the pandas documentation and learned enough Python in ten minutes to test the result.  If the data set is invalid but must be used as-is then Deepankar has the solution and you should accept that answer.

Comment: @Losolak : I suggest that you  look at the CSV data in a text editor rather than Excel or Jupiter to see what it really contains.  The fact that all the data ends up in column A in the screenshot of whatever that is a screenshot of suggests that you have either default copy&pasted it in Excel or that the whole line is enclosed in quotes - which Excel would do if you default copy & pasted the CSV in Excel then exported it as a CSV.

Comment: @Losolak : The whole Excel/Jupiter column thing probably deserves a separate question.  But I strongly suggest that you post the CSV as text rather than screenshots.  The screen rendering is dependent on the software arsing the CSV, anyone would want to see the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the formatting of the CSV file you're using is very poor. You should never put multiple data types in a single column. However, it is possible to separate multiple data types present in a single column.

Here's how you can do that:

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', usecols=[0], sep=';', header=None)
colA = df[0][1:].apply(literal_eval)
print(colA.head())
```

**Output:**

```
>> 1    ([5, 6, 7, 8], 0, 210)
>> 2       ([2, 2, 0], 1, 110)
>> 3          ([2, 7], 0, 200)
>> Name: A, dtype: object
```

Use `;` as separator because it is not used anywhere in that column.
`colA` is a pandas Series object. 
Column values are converted into a `tuple` of 3 data types: `List`, `int`, `int`. 
You can iterate over them like this:

```
for row in colA:
    l, t, a = row
    print(f'List={l}, True={t}, Amount={a}')
```

**Output:**

```
>> List=[5, 6, 7, 8], True=0, Amount=210
>> List=[2, 2, 0], True=1, Amount=110
>> List=[2, 7], True=0, Amount=200
```

Comment: Hi Deepankar Sharma, thanks for your thoughts. I think that is quite what I need. I know, the csv is not perfect, but it is exactly what has to be done. Of course, there are plenty of rows, it's only for simplification.I did exactly what you suggested, unfortunately there is the following error: "AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'A'". I compared the data.csv with the data.csv uploaded into the notebook. And they are right, in the csv in the jupiter notebook there are no columns to see. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Losolak It seems like the CSV file doesn't have headers. You should pass `header=None` in `read_csv` method. Check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks, Deepankar Sharma, that works perfectly. I voted, unfortunately this was my first try to get to know stackoverflow, so my reputation is below 15, so you can't see it. You really helped me a lot!

Comment: @Losolak: New users can't upvote an answer, but you can accept it if it answers your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers